# Python - Function Parameter Class Type Within Same Class

Tags: python

I have code like this:

```
class Direction(Enum):
    ...
    def rotateClockwise(cls, direction):
```

Is it possible to add a type requirement of the class Direction within the class itself? I ask because when I try using the normal decorator syntax, it says `Direction` isn't defined, which makes sense.

I tried this, and would like to be able to do something to the effect of this:

```
class Direction(Enum):
    ...
    def rotateClockwise(cls, direction: Direction) -> Direction:
```

So If there is a correct way, what is it?

Comment: Annotations are simply text explanations. The types or output are in no way enforced by the act of annotating.

Comment: For 3.6 or earlier, `"Direction"` is good enough for mypy and other static type checkers, and hopefully you don't care what you end up with at runtime. For 3.7, [things are improved a bit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/), but since 3.7 is still in beta, there's a good chance you can't require it.